# R Studio - Big dataset making the graph look like a bar chart

Tags: r, graph, linegraph

I'm running a large data set with 2524 rows, when I want to run the plot code below the graph looks like a bar chart, I cant figure out why. I used ggplot2 and it ended up changing the data to text.

```
plot(SamAll$OpenSam, type="l", lwd=2, main= "2014-2018 Samsung Open Stock")
```

A line plot is really what I want to achieve.
Help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: `plot` is a "generic" function that calls a more specific function (a "method") depending on what type of data you feed in.  What type of data is `SamAll$OpenSam`?  If it's simply numeric data, `plot` is going to make a histogram.  One way around this is to be more specific about what you want each axis to represent: `plot(x=1:nrow(SamAll), y=SamAll$OpenSam, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your variable is saved as a factor. You might need to change it as a numeric variable, or you can change it to numeric within the plot function:

```
plot( as.numeric(SamAll$OpenSam), 
  type="l", lwd=2, main= "2014-2018 Samsung Open Stock")
```

Consider the following as an illustrative example

```
# Save 2524 values as a factor
x = as.factor(floor(rnorm(2524, 100, 10)))
> plot(x, type="l", lwd=2)
```

We get the following:

[image: xasfactor]

Convert `x` to numeric

```
> plot( as.numeric(x), type="l", lwd=2)
```

Now we get the line graph

[image: x as line]